# Como redimensionar uma imagem em c#?

Tags: c#, imagem

Estou trabalhando num aplicação que recebe upload de imagens. Acontece que o cliente as vezes envia essas imagens com uma resolução muito grande, o que não é necessário no nosso caso (chegando as 7MB).

Preciso que a imagem tenha até, no máximo, 1200 de largura (a resolução é sempre 3x4).

Acontece que eu não tenho muita experiência com C#...

Como redimensionar uma imagem com C#? É necessário instalar alguma biblioteca adicional, ou já existe alguma biblioteca padrão?

Comment: é uma aplicação desktop ou web? se for web vale redimensionar ela no client antes de enviar, mas se banda não for problema na transferência é bem fácil resolver isso no c#

Comment: @LeandroAngelo É web. No caso, eu gostaria de redimensionar no servidor mesmo.

Comment: Tentou assim? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp

Answer (score 6):

No link sugerido pelo @DiegoSantos há um método que permite redimensionar a imagem.

Fiz um teste com uma imagem PNG com a dimensão de 1920x1080 e o tamanho 2,46 MB. Redimensionei a imagem para 600x400 e o tamanho ficou em 580 KB, e manteve uma ótima qualidade ainda.

Método para redimensionar a imagem:

```
Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);

            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

## Explicação do método ResizeImage

O método `ResizeImage()` acima usa as seguintes classes para mudar a resolução sem afetar a qualidade da imagem:

- [Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) é uma estrutura que representa o local e o tamanho da imagem
- [Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) contém os dados referentes aos pixels da imagem, também guarda informações dos atributos da imagem, além de ser a nova imagem com a resolução alterada.
- [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) encapsula a superfície de desenho [GDI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms533798(v=vs.85).aspx). Graças a esta classe que mantemos a qualidade.
- [ImageAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) mantém as informações correspondentes as cores e metadados da imagem, esses dados são manipulados durante a renderização.

Um exemplo de implementação do método:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    Stream myStream = null;

    openFileDialog.FileName = "MinhaImagem";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {
                    var image = Image.FromStream(myStream);

                    var newImage = ResizeImage(image, 600, 400);
                    newImage.Save("c:\\newImage.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }            
}
```

## Explicação da implementação do método ResizeImage

Na implementação acima usei uma imagem Png e um `OpenFileDialog` para teste, o método ResizeImage retorna a imagem modificada, em seguida salvei ela no disco especificando o formato da imagem no método `save()` que no caso é Png.

Vale lembrar que seria interessante fazer alguns testes unitários neste método para ver se retorna algum resultado incomum.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24199315/5429980